# Setter not called in one place, working fine elsewhere

Tags: javascript, setter

I created a js class:

```
class Drawer {

}
```

Then added a constructor with a single argument:

```
constructor (elemId) {
    // get element by passed id
    this.elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
    // make sure the element was found
    console.log(elem);

    // listen for clicks on the found element
    this.elem.addEventListener('click', this.handleDimClick);

    // listen for touch events (start, move, cancel, end)
    document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', this.handleTouchStart);
    ...
}
```

This logs the correct element to console.

The handleDimClick function sets a property to `false`.

Here's the relevant property:

```
get open() {
    return this.isOpen;
}

set open(value) {
    console.log('setting open to ' + value);
    this.isOpen = value;
    // code omitted
}
```

Here is the `handleDimClick` method:

```
handleDimClick() {
    console.log('handleDimClick setting open to false');
    this.open = false;
    console.log('handleDimClick open should be false');
}
```

This, for some reason, only logs 2 lines to the console:

```
handleDimClick setting open to false
handleDimClick open should be false
```

One of the touch handling functions also sets the `open` property:

```
handleTouchEnd(e) {
    console.log('handleTouchEnd setting open to ' + (irrelevant));
    this.open = (irrelevant);
    console.log('handleTouchEnd open should be ' + (irrelevant));
}
```

And as expected logs to the console:

```
handleTouchEnd setting open to false
setting open to false
handleTouchEnd open should be false
```

I'm absolutely out of ideas on why this happens. I tried Ctrl+Shift+R to refresh without cache, but it didn't help. I can see the file is ok in the developer console. The behavior is consistent.